# Reverse Compliment of DNA using user Input String

Tags: python

I want to print the reverse compliment of a user input string of DNA. 
For Background: 
Input can be any combination of the characters A C G or T. 
A and T are compliments and G and C are compliments of one another. 
My goal is to take the user input and print out the reverse compliment of that string.

So far I have been able to reverse the user input string, but I am unsure of how to apply the compliment. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
print("Enter a DNA string:")

string = str(input("S> "))

reverse_string = (string[::-1])

print(reverse_string)
```

My code so far prints out the user input string reversed, but not the compliment.

Example input:

S> AAAACCCGGT

My output TGGCCCAAAA

Desired Output ACCGGGTTTT

Comment: add several examples of input and outputs please

Answer (score 1):

Just use a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to map chars to their complements, apply the mapping to the reverse string and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the chars back together:

```
# complement mapping
c = {'A': 'T', 'T': 'A', 'G': 'C', 'C': 'G'}

s = 'AAAACCCGGT'  # do not shadow string module
rev_comp = ''.join(map(c.get, s[::-1]))
# 'ACCGGGTTTT'
```

Answer (score 0):

The compliment part can be done via a mapping of A -> T (and T -> A) and similarly for G, C. Use a comprehension to build the compliment string and then reverse it.

```
dna = 'AAAACCCGGT'

compliment_mapping = {'A': 'T', 'T': 'A', 'G': 'C', 'C': 'G'}

compliment = ''.join(compliment_mapping[c] for c in dna)

reverse_compliment = compliment[::-1]

print(reverse_compliment)
```

Output:

```
ACCGGGTTTT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to store the compliment relationship. In addition, the use of `reversed` avoids creating a reversed list in the memory, reducing the memory footprint.

```
print("Enter a DNA string:")
compliment = {'A': 'T', 'T': 'A', 'G': 'C', 'C': 'G'}

while True:
    dna = str(input("S> "))
    reverse_dna = ''.join(compliment[bp] for bp in reversed(dna))
    print(reverse_dna)
```

Here is the output.

```
Enter a DNA string:
S> AAAACCCGGT
ACCGGGTTTT
S> ACCGGGTTTT
AAAACCCGGT
```

You can see that the reverse compliment of the reverse compliment is the original DNA string.